# Firebase realtime database transaction returns null

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I am using firebase transaction in my real-time database to fetch the latest count but it returns null instead of the count.I don't know what i am doing wrong in this query.

```
  export const updateDashboardCount = (id, childName) =>
  db.ref('dashboard/' + id).child(childName).transaction((data) => {
    console.log('data is', data);
  });
```

Where id is -LT0uc53cRmufLotuGd0 and ChildName is employees.

Output I am receiving is null

[image: Dashboard]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should return `data`, as follows:

```
  export const updateDashboardCount = (id, childName) =>
  db.ref('dashboard/' + id).child(childName).transaction((data) => {
    console.log('data is', data);
    return data;
  });
```

I guess that you are going to update the `data` value in a future version and not only log it to the console.

---

**Update:**

As said in the comment, with the above code you will first get a `console.log` with `null` **and then** a `console.log` with the correct data, due to the asynchronicity.

If you want to get only one "correct" `console.log`, you could as follows (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction))

```
  db.ref('dashboard/' + id).child(childName).transaction((data) => {
      return data;
  }, function (error, committed, snapshot) {
      if (error) {
          console.log('Transaction failed abnormally!', error);
      } else if (!committed) {
          console.log('We aborted the transaction (because ada already exists).');
      } else {
          console.log('data is' + snapshot.val());
      }
  });
```

Comment: But in console i am receiving it as null

Comment: If you don't add the return you will get a console.log with null. If on the opposite you add a return, you will first get a console.log with null  and then a console.log with the correct data. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Null is intended value, if you look at documentation. Your issue was that you didn't return anything, therefore undefined return caused transaction to stop.

Easy fix

```
 export const updateDashboardCount = (id, childName) =>
  db.ref('dashboard/' + id).child(childName).transaction((data) => {
    if(data===null)
       return data;
    console.log('data is', data);
  });
```

Data will be correctly set now